# K8s Nginx Ingress in Rancher - Timeout not working

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, rancher

I have a service and pod(s) both working perfectly in my infrastructure with a simple ingress.

However there are a couple of cases which the front-end request a PDF generation of the backend that can take around 1,5 - 2seconds.
While I said to the team developing that they should:

- try to speed it up the process by making the code a bit leaner or
- make it work differently by firing a request, asking if it is done in separate intervals and downloading it when ready (3 or more shortly lived requests)

They just can't do it now and I said I would do my best... to which is apparently not enough...

I have the following **Ingress YAML**:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tool-ingress
  namespace: testing
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: tool.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: tool-service
            port: 
              number: 80 
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - tool.example.com
    secretName: mySecret
```

Now I still keep getting a timeout in the browser after 1s.
I've tried several variants but I can't get this to work. I have created the ingress directly on rancher but the yaml above I tried deploying directly with `kubectl apply`. Both variants did not change a thing.

**QUESTION(s)**

- Is there something I am clearly missing?
- Is this something I have to check/change on rancher that might be taking precedence over these values?
- I've read in a lot of places that people go into the "generated ingress pod" and check the generated annotation but I don't see anything like a pod being created with my ingress

  - I do have the ingress-controllers on the `ingress-nginx` namespace but I thought they are for internally controlling the communication between the nodes on the cluster (I have a 3 node cluster) since I see one deployed on each cluster

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Info:
K8s Rev: v1.19.6
Rancher Rev: v2.5.5

Comment: even with default settings the timeout is more than one second. I guess you have a different problem.

Comment: What people mean by ingress pod is the pod of the ingress controller itself. This pod will monitor the cluster and react to ingress resources you create, more or less. There are a few more moving pieces to that, but it's not that critical important right now. It depends on how you deployed your ingress controller where you find this pod. If you list your namespaces, probably there is one that's called ingress-nginx.

Comment: Anything you might think where I can start to look? I have logs on my gateway service and I see the data incoming and I see the response being returned after the timeout occurred on the front end so definitely no backend issues. I also found the info that it was 60s here on the docs: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/

Comment: maybe an issue with your frontend. Can you try with curl?

Comment: I just did. I get a "504 gateway timeout" and "nginx/1.19.2" 

Front end is a simple JS logic that use axios... I checked and there are no other configs there

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the info... I will do a bit of homework and check

Comment: But you may be right with the 504. I think nginx gives that if the backend exceeds the time to response, but was reachable. If it's not reachable at all, it's a 502. But very strange that it happens after 1 second. That's way too quick. Can you check the logs of the ingress controller pod? Maybe in some strange world its because the response body is too large.